# Jmeter - how to get SLA metric

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Does exists any way to calculate count of requests under SLA in jmeter from UI? For example, count of requests that response time < 400 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simplest solution is to use [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to save Label, Elapsed Time and / or Latency to a CSV file, which will generate raw output like this:

   ```
   elapsed,label
   423,sampler1
   452,sampler2
   958,sampler1
   152,sampler1
   ```

   And from here you can take it to any other tool (awk, Excel, etc.) to filter results you want.
2. Another option is to use [BeanShell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to generate such report on the fly. Something like this:

   ```
   long responseTime = sampleResult.getEndTime() - sampleResult.getStartTime();
   if(responseTime < 400) {
       FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("myreport.csv", true);
       PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);
       this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
       print(sampleResult.getSampleLabel() + "," + responseTime);
       f.close(); 
   }
   ```

   This method, though, may not be performant enough if you are planning to run a stress test with many (more than 200-300) users and many operations that "fit" the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago and wrote a little tool - see https://github.com/sgoeschl/jmeter-sla-report

Answer (score -1):

JMeter provides OOTB a Web Report that provides tons of informations regarding your load test using standard metrics like APDEX, Percentiles ...

See this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

If you still want this, do the following:

Add as a child of your request add a [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion):

[image: Duration Assertion]

All response below it will be marked as failing. 
And in the report, you'll have the count of successful requests meeting this SLA criterion.